# Sitecore: Anonymous Page Previews

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-workflow

Is it possible to implement an anonymous page preview in SiteCore? We have a a requirement to send an authorisation email to a group of people to review the content prior to it being released, but the requirement for the user to login to SiteCore first before the preview link works breaks the user experience.  Ideally we need a URL which can be generated (or derived) during the workflow process that is essentially a public preview of the page.

Is this possible?

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. It takes a bit of work though.

http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/09/publish-to-pre-production-web-database.html?m=1

Comment: Very interesting - thanks! I'll give that a review, and see if we can get it going :)